# Less than characer [<] breaking preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex

I've run into some trouble with a regex, and I can't seem to figure out the reason for this behaviour.

```
$RGX = "~(\w+)\s*([=:<>])\s*(.*?(?=&&|\+|$))~";

$STR  = "date<something";

preg_match_all($RGX, $STR, $SearchParameters, PREG_SET_ORDER);

print_r($SearchParameters);
```

When using the regex, a problem arises **only** when the input string contains the "less than" character, as in the above example.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => date date
            [2] => <
            [3] => something
        )

)
```

Comment: [I cannot repro](https://ideone.com/qZ9Bs3).

Comment: Don't speak php, but after a quick google - could it have something with ["Heredoc"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to do?

Comment: I bet you are looking at the output of `print_r()` in the browser but not to the page source. The output of `print_r()` looks like this: https://3v4l.org/4usvT#output

Comment: Have you tried to escape special characters or use their Unicode values?

Comment: You were right axiac! Occured to me just now - thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it out!

The problem was that I viewed the result in a browser and of course the browser interpreted the "<" character as the beginning of a new HTML object. Bloody hell.

Doing a `foreach` on the Parameters and using `htmlentities()` showed that the regex actually works as it should.